# Pourquoi et quand l'ordre des mots en français est devenu fixe ?

Tags: histoire, ordre-des-mots, latin

J'ai lu les articles suivants (en anglais):

- [Latin Grammar - Word Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_grammar#Word_order) | Grammaire latin - Ordre des mots
- [Vulgar Latin - Grammar (enumeration of changes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin#Grammar) | Latin vulgaire - Grammaire
- [French Grammar - Word Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_grammar#Word_order) | Grammaire français - Ordre des mots

Mais je n'ai pas trouvé quand l'ordre des mots, de libre en latin, est passé à fixe en français. Pourriez-vous dire pourquoi et quand l'ordre de mots est devenu imposé ?

Comment: Il me semble que toutes les langues modernes occidentales (pas le roumain) dérivées du latin ont l'ordre des mots sujet-verbe-objet. Donc c'est probablement une évolution qui avait déjà commencé avec le latin tardif (en même temps que la progressive disparition des déclinaisons des noms et des adjectifs). Du coup, les experts sur le sujet sont probablement plus à trouver sur [linguistics.se].

Comment: _On les peut mettre premièrement comme vous avez dit: Belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux me font mourir d'amour. Ou bien: D'amour mourir me font, belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux. Ou bien: Vos yeux beaux d'amour me font, belle Marquise, mourir. Ou bien: Mourir vos beaux yeux, belle Marquise, d'amour me font. Ou bien: Me font vos yeux beaux mourir, belle Marquise, d'amour._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quelques éléments à la lecture de *[Histoire d'une langue le français, des lointaines origines à nos jours](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Histoire_d_une_langue_le_fran%C3%A7ais.html?id=kixcAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)*<sup>1</sup>, de [Marcel Cohen](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Cohen). Les citations sont entre guillemets.

En latin les noms ont presque toujours la marque de leur rôle grâce aux désinences qui indiquent la fonction du mot dans la phrase, du coup l'ordre des mots n'était pas fixé. Cependant le latin marquait une préférence pour certains ordres comme le rejet du verbe en fin de phrase.

Certaines déclinaisons commencèrent à disparaître en latin vulgaire mais l'ancien français comportait encore certaines marques de cas.  Le sujet  et le complément d'objet direct sont encore marqués par leur forme et leur place n'est pas fixé par rapport au verbe.
« Cependant certains ordres étaient devenus habituels ou même obligatoires. « Ainsi un attribut avant le verbe *être* est de préférence en tête : *grant est la plaigne*.
Le complément de nom sans préposition (cas régime) est toujours après le nom complété : *en l ermitage frère Ogrin*. Dans l'ensemble le verbe était de préférence en deuxième place. »

À la fin de la période d'ancien français il ne restait plus que deux cas (sujet et objet direct) et la déclinaison disparaît  complètement dans la première partie du moyen français.
«  Peut-on dire, en simplifiant les choses, que la perte définitive de la distinction des deux formes a fait que la place des mots s'est fixée, de manière que le sujet soit reconnu à sa place avant le verbe ? Il est plus probable que la tendance à adopter cet ordre a été concomitante et même en partie antérieure à la perte de la déclinaison et a contribué pour sa part à sa perte. »

La fixation progressive de l'ordre des mots modernes : sujet, verbe, compléments, s'est faite en moyen français, le complément d'objet n'étant plus distingué que par sa place. Marcel Cohen suggère que la place des mots s'est fixée avant la perte de ce qu'il restait des déclinaisons.   Il semble que « divers auteurs du 13<sup>e</sup> siècle et début du 14<sup>e</sup> siècle employaient la déclinaison de manière voulue par écrit, alors qu'il n'en usaient pas dans leur langage parlé, et même que certains n'en faisaient pas usage orthographique ».

**En résumé** :
La place du nom complément d’objet s’est fixée après le verbe au 13<sup>e</sup> siècle. La place du sujet à son tour s’est fixée devant le verbe durant le 14<sup>e</sup> siècle.  La déclinaison des noms et des adjectifs, qui permettait souvent d’identifier le sujet, a disparu au 14<sup>e</sup> siècle. 
L'ordre moderne sujet-verbe-complément a tendu à se fixer au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Je signale [ce document](http://anr-leonard.ens-lyon.fr/IMG/doc/seminaireIII-exemplier.doc), un cours universitaire très accessible, qui présente en détail l'évolution de l'ordre des mots de l'ancien français au français moderne.
Et ces deux sites qui traitent aussi du sujet :
[Morphologie et syntaxe du latin au français](http://bbouillon.free.fr/univ/hl/Fichiers/Cours/synt.htm).(Cours universitaire)
[Histoire de la langue française, par Jacques Leclerc](http://www.axl.cefan.ulaval.ca/francophonie/histlngfrn.htm)

<sup>1. Livre grand public qui s'adresse à des noms spécialistes, et dont la lecture est passionnante pour peu qu'on s'intéresse à la langue française.</sup>

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse détaillée et l'information supplémentaire ! Je vais lire ce document quand mon français est devenu un peu mieux.